# jsPDF Plugin NOT working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found JavaScript plugin  [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) which convert HTML to PDF file document.
I find it very useful but at a certain point in time the plugin fails with an error in console:

```
jspdf.js:8009 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
at Renderer.renderParagraph (jspdf.js:8009)
at Renderer.setBlockBoundary (jspdf.js:8059)
at DrillForContent (jspdf.js:7611)
at DrillForContent (jspdf.js:7579)
at DrillForContent (jspdf.js:7579)
at DrillForContent (jspdf.js:7579)
at DrillForContent (jspdf.js:7579)
at DrillForContent (jspdf.js:7579)
at jspdf.js:7747
at done (jspdf.js:7622)
```

The problem I found is the plugin fails converting some html string.
Does someone know any working the plugin to solve the problem:

```
//conver to PDF
  SMSLiTe('click',bigPipe.saveDoc,function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(this), p  = $(bigPipe.printArea);
  if (!a.hasClass(bigPipe.d)) {
     a.addClass(bigPipe.d).prepend(bigPipe.loading);
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  var elementHandler = {
    '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };


  var source  = $('#print-area').html();
  doc.fromHTML(
      source,
      15,
      15,
      {
        'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
      },function(){doc.save(t +'.pdf')});

      setTimeout(function(){a.removeClass(bigPipe.d).find('span').remove()},600);
    }
  });
```

Please how do I solve this problem? I have lots of valid HTML stored as student notes in database and when I user request to view a note I pull this html and display it then an event to is bind to a button to convert the container to pdf file document.

Please help me solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: The `jsPDF` you linked to does not have a `.fromHTML` method documented

Comment: Can you give some examples of what HTML is failing? Also, don't forget that the browser maybe altering your 'valid HTML that is coming from the database.

Comment: It works when I change the source to : $('#print-area').text(); but that is not what I want. see documentation here: http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#addHTML

Comment: I'm I not using the plugin well?

Comment: I also read something from here : http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Comment: github for this plugin: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF